# DRF: How to create serializer that uses a field to search if object with given ID exists in database, and if so use this object as foreign key

Tags: python, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have following 2 models:

```
class Student(BaseModel):
        external_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        name= models.CharField(max_length=30)
        last_name= models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Book(BaseModel):
        student = models.OneToOneField(
            "student.Student",
            related_name="books",
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
        book_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        book_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I want to create such serializer that will create a Book only if there is a Student with provided external_id.

```
class BooksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = [
            "student",
            "book_name",
            "book_type",
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        student_external_id = validated_data.pop('student')
        st = Student.objects.get(
            external_id=student_external_id
        )
        book = Book.objects.create(
            student=st,
            book_name=validated_data["book_name"],
            book_type=validated_data["book_type"],
        )

        return book
```

I have written this code but obviously it doesn't work. I used nested serializers to do similar things but I don't want to create Student this time, only check if exisit's and the use it as relation, otherwise throw error that such student doesn't exists.
Maybe it's bad approach first of all? Maybe I shouldn't try to create separete endpoint for books, and try to use patch method for Student and inside of it create object Book to given Student?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) . It checks sended value exists, if not exists raises ValidationError. Try this:

```
class BooksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    student = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Student.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = [
            "student",
            "book_name",
            "book_type",
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        book = Book.objects.create(
            student=student,
            book_name=validated_data["book_name"],
            book_type=validated_data["book_type"],
        )

        return book
```

If you want to use different field from primary key, then you can use [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield). You should add your lookup field with `slug_field` key.

```
class BooksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    student = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Student.objects.all(), slug_field='external_id')

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = [
            "student",
            "book_name",
            "book_type",
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        book = Book.objects.create(
            student=validated_data["student"],
            book_name=validated_data["book_name"],
            book_type=validated_data["book_type"],
        )

        return book
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't think it's solution for me. I need to know if student exists by external_id which is a string, not PK. external id is a string, UUID which is unique.

Comment: @Beorn You can use SlugRelatedField then, I updated answer.

Comment: Ok, it's working. If someone will need this in the future: use validated_data["student"] instead of student and SlugRelatedField instead of SlugRelatedRelatedField.